# click count in Activities

Tags: android, click-counting

My android app project need to add a new function of saving the click count of some view(such as button,picture, and so on) in my activities.
how to settle this with proper way(in architecture view point)? should i override all the onClick()?

Comment: my project has nearly 100 activities,should i edit  the onClick() in all of them? i tried to add storing of the click count in the supperclass of my avtivities,but the supperclass is an abstract class and abstract methods do not specify a body.                    or should i create a interface(ICounter), and put the save job in that?

Comment: My project has many activities,extend an abstract "BaseActivity",BaseActivity has "protected abstract void setListener()", i can't add click-counting method in that setListener() because it is abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set an `onclicklistener` to the desired views, store the click count in a field and increment that field when the `onClick()` action occurs.

Comment: thank you , my project has nearly 100 activities,should i edit  the onClick() in all of them? i tried to add storing of the click count in the supperclass of my avtivities,but the supperclass is an abstract class and abstract methods do not specify a body...

Comment: I think you should set the listeners inside the implemented class not in the superclass.. and I guess there is no other practical way to find out what's clicked and count them.. By the way, 100 activities sounds like a overkill..

Comment: should I use a new Interface to let my activities implements it?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your questions if you edit your original question and add some code snippets.

Comment: My project has many activities,extend an abstract "BaseActivity",BaseActivity has "protected abstract void setListener()", i can't add click-counting method in that setListener() because it is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture this by setting an onClickListener and updating a global counter